# Is it right to catch boost::interrupted_exception?

Tags: c++, exception, boost

In my application, threads can be interrupted with boost::thread::interrupt. I want to reuse interrupted thread, can I just catch boost::interrupted_exception, or it is ideologically incorrect?

Comment: The interruption mechanism exists purely as an aid to you. What interruption actually means to you is for you to decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to reuse interrupted thread

It [looks like](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/thread-interruption-in-boost-thread-library.html) you can (emphasis added):

> boost::thread_interrupted is just a normal exception, so it can be
>   caught, just like any other exception. This is why the "interrupted"
>   flag is cleared when the exception is thrown — if a thread catches and
>   handles the interruption, it is perfectly acceptable to interrupt it
>   again. **This can be used, for example, when a worker thread that is
>   processing a series of independent tasks — if the current task is
>   interrupted, the worker can handle the interruption and discard the
>   task, and move onto the next task**, which can then in turn be
>   interrupted. It also allows the thread to catch the exception and
>   terminate itself by other means, such as returning error codes, or
>   translating the exception to pass through module boundaries.